# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext causes choppy Navigation Controller Back animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

I have a UINavigationController which has View Controller A. I push onto it View Controller B. View Controller B contains an Image View which gets its image loaded asynchronously by the following code:

```
let ss = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)

ss!.start { (snapshot, error) in

    guard let snappy = snapshot else {
        return
    }

    let snap = snappy.image

    ...
    // create a pinView which gets combined with the snapshot image
    ...

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(snap.size, false, snap.scale)

    snap.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 - pinView.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2 - pinView.frame.height/2), size: CGSize(width: pinView.frame.width, height: pinView.frame.height))

    pinView.drawHierarchy(in: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    let finalSnap = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.snapshotView.image = finalSnap
}
```

Whenever I press the back button from VC B to go back to VC A, and if the image has not finished rendering yet, the pop animation is very choppy/sluggish/stuttery. I commented lines to see which line caused the  sluggishness and it happens on `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext` (if I press < Back before that line gets called, then this problem occurs)

I tried canceling the MKMapSnapshotter via `ss.cancel()`, I tried wrapping the UIGraphics context portion within `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`, and I also tried setting a flag during `viewWillDisappear` and checking if `isMovingFromParentViewController` to tell it to not run that line, but since the image creation is async and fired off immediately, there's no guarantee it has loaded yet. None of them have worked for me.

Does anyone have insight into how to properly tell my VC B to either stop all processes, or how I can fix this? If I let the snapshot image fully load then this problem doesn't occur, but I can't count on that happening.

Comment: Try creating the image in the background. Only the assignment to the image view needs to be on the main queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @rmaddy 's suggestion I moved the image creation to the background thread. I did run into an issue, however, that `drawHierarchy(in: rect, afterScreenUpdates: true)` can not be called on a background thread, so I changed the way I was creating my pinView so that I would only have to add a UIImage to my current graphics context via draw in rect.

The final code worked like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(snap.size, false, snap.scale)

    snap.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: self.frame.width/2 - pinView.frame.width/2, y: self.frame.height/2 - pinView.frame.height/2), size: CGSize(width: pinView.frame.width, height: pinView.frame.height))

    pinView.image?.draw(in: rect) // changed this to allow background thread execution

    let finalSnap = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // main thread image view assignment    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.snapshotView.image = finalSnap
    }          
}
```